# How to remove address numbers from Cloudmade tiles?

Tags: cloudmade

I'm using Cloudmade to generate tiles using a custom style I created. It's exactly how I want it, except that at zoom level 17, it shows the street address numbers on the map. Is there a way to remove these? I see nothing in the style editor to do it, but I see that some styles don't display these.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this could be disabled by checking "hide all non-editable features". Not sure what the other features it turns off are, I don't notice any.